# Saving as .rtf in MS Word (MS Office 365 ProPlus - Word v15.0.4779.1002)

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating letters in Word and using angle brackets (< and >) to create tags for the next step of a mail merge type process.  When I save the file as an .rtf and open it in Notepad, additional characters are added between the left bracket (<) and the first letter of the tag.

Example:  I type `<ExampleTag>` in Word and save as .rtf.  I open the .rtf in Notepad and this tag shows up as `<}{\hclrt\fsc8 \acf2\fas29 \hclrt\fcs0 \f99\fas44\id8172283 ExampleTag>`

This does not happen on all tags, but about 90% of the time.  Can anyone explain why these extra characters are added and possibly a way to avoid them?  Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked to see if I could find the meaning of those codes.  [RTF spec](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) did not have anything for \hclrt, but Google searching for "hclrt" did show some PDF files.  It may be that \hclrt is rather Word-specific: I believe RTF permits programs to use non-standard codes (that non-supporting programs will know to just ignore).  Or maybe your Word is not saving in pure RTF (perhaps due to an add-on).  Regardless, I don't think Notepad is causing troubles (in this particular case)-- those codes are part of the saved file. +1 Techie007

Answer (score 1):

Those are the [RTF control codes](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading2) for setting fonts, formatting, etc.

`Notepad` doesn't support RTF, so it shows the RFS control codes.  If you open it in `Wordpad` you'll notice the codes are not displayed (as Wordpad can process RTF).

Word in notorious for adding a bunch of extra/unneeded formatting to it's pages, but even Wordpad adds a couple lines of control codes, basically just because it's RTF.

Easiest way to avoid it:  Stop using RTF, and save as Plain Text instead.